# How to upload file to IPFS by keeping same CID

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ipfs, js-ipfs

1. Store 2 image in IPFS and *pin it*.
2. The IPFS URI should be like

ipfs://ipfs.io/hashCID/O.png

ipfs://ipfs.io/hashCID/1.png

3. Here hashCID should be same.
   Just change the next token id and you should be able to retrieve the image.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's not possible to upload two files to IPFS with the came CID (although IPNS might be what you're looking for here).

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/content-addressing/):

> CIDs are based on the content’s cryptographic hash. That means:
>
> - Any difference in the content will produce a different CID and
> - The same content added to two different IPFS nodes using the same settings will produce the same CID.

---

So you'll get the same `hashCID` only if both `0.png` and `1.png` have the same content and are added (to the IPFS) with the same settings.